# How to install xclip on Centos 8?

Tags: centos8

I recently started using Centos 8 on my Workstation and there is no `xsel` or `xclip`

Is there something wrong or is it on purpose, that `xclip` is not available?

Here is the output of `dnf repolist`, maybe I'm missing some must-have repo?

```
repo id                                                                             repo name                                                                                                               status
AppStream                                                                           CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                                                                    5.089
Atom                                                                                Atom Editor                                                                                                               142
BaseOS                                                                              CentOS-8 - Base                                                                                                         2.843
amdgpu-pro-local                                                                    AMD amdgpu Pro local repository                                                                                            70
docker-ce-stable                                                                    Docker CE Stable - x86_64                                                                                                  57
*epel                                                                               Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                                                          3.643
extras                                                                              CentOS-8 - Extras                                                                                                           3
virtualbox                                                                          Oracle Linux / RHEL / CentOS-8 / x86_64 - VirtualBox                                                                        4
```

Answer (score 3):

First Enable EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) repo on CentOS 8 to install extra packages such xclip.

Step 1: Install epel repo

```
# yum install epel-release.noarch
             or
# dnf install epel-release
```

Step 2: Install xclip from the EPEL repo

```
# dnf install xclip
Last metadata expiration check: 0:06:09 ago on Mon 07 Feb 2022 10:39:39 AM IST.
Dependencies resolved.
=============================================================================================================================================================
 Package                             Architecture                         Version                                   Repository                          Size
=============================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 xclip                               x86_64                               0.13-8.el8                                epel                                35 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compile from yourself:

```sh
# Obtain the sourcecode
git clone https://github.com/astrand/xclip.git
./bootstrap
./configure
make
make install
```

Verify that is installed:

```sh
man xclip
```

Answer (score 1):

In Centos 8 while running pyperclip.copy("Hello"), I found centos 8 don't have xclip and so the package gives me error.
I have search all packages but repository of Centos8 don't have any similar packages.

I resolve this in following steps.

## Install libXmu and X11 development library

sudo yum install libXmu-devel libX11-devel

## Obtain the sourcecode

git clone https://github.com/astrand/xclip.git

./bootstrap

./configure

make

sudo make install

Then test install
man xclip

Now I can use pyperclip in python to use clipboard.